# The usage of "There you go"

Tags: phrase-usage

> Bad guy: Come on, Tin Man, just pull the trigger.
>   Pull it.
>   You can run.
>   Go on.
>   Run.
>   Run!
>   **There you go.**
>   Run. Run!
>
> *--Robocop 2014*

I have come across numerous "There you go." in movies. I have looked it up in dictionaries, but I couldn't well fit the meanings to the scene.

Would you explain how and when this idiomatic expression is used in daily conversation.

Comment: Try this page: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/there; it's right down at the bottom.

Comment: I tried that one, but I don't need an explanation here. All I want to know is the usage. @Damkerng T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"There you go" (often pronounced quickly and slurred, more like "there ya'go") is used in several different situations, either as encouragement or confirmation.

In the case you are quoting above it's being used similarly to the encouragement you might give to a child who is just learning to walk: "there you go" as in "that is correct, you've 'got' it now, you are doing it now" (where 'got' in this case refers to having acquired the skill.)

It can also be used in a slightly different situation as a confirmation that I'm giving you something that you asked for:

Person A: "Please pass the salt."
Person B: (as they are handing the salt shaker to person A), "there you go."
Person C: "thanks."

Comment: The last example is probably the most commonly used one.